# Pulling a value from Xml in a column

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have a table in Sql server that stores Xml data in one of its columns. 
The Xml column data looks like this:

```
<TestDef Weight="0" FailValue="2" ConceptID="-327">
  <ToleranceDef ObjectType="SomeName" TargetValue="0"TargetRange="2" />
</TestDef>
```

I need to write a query that fetches out all the conceptId's from each rows Xml column.
Here it would be -327

I know I can cast the Xml column to a nvarchar(max) then use some reg exp to get the value but not sure how to use the regular expression

Answer (score 5):

Here's an example using a table variable. It will be the same concept with an actual table:

```sql
Declare @XmlTable table (
    Id Integer Identity,
    XmlValue XML
)

Insert Into @XmlTable (XmlValue) values ('<TestDef Weight="0" FailValue="2" ConceptID="-327"><ToleranceDef ObjectType="SomeName" TargetValue="0" TargetRange="2" /></TestDef>')
Insert Into @XmlTable (XmlValue) values ('<TestDef Weight="0" FailValue="2" ConceptID="-325"><ToleranceDef ObjectType="SomeName" TargetValue="0" TargetRange="2" /></TestDef>')


select
    Id,
    XmlValue,
    XmlValue.value('(/TestDef/@ConceptID)[1]', 'integer') as ConceptId
from
    @XmlTable
```

Comment: instead of using a table varible for your demo you might want to try [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/290e5/1)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, definitely looks like a useful site!